# How to do a site specific search with Bing API?

Tags: c#, bing-api

I would like to do a site specific search using the using the Bing API. Here is my program:

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.BingSearch
{    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rootUri = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
            var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUri));
            var accountKey = "xxxxxxx";
            bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
            string query = "SQL Server";
            var t = bingContainer.News(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            t.AddQueryOption("site", "computerworld.com");
            var resultNews = t.Execute();    
            foreach(var item in resultNews)
            {
                var g = item.ID;
                Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " - " + item.Source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program runs (assuming you put in a valid account key) and returns results. Unfortunately it does not limit the results to computerworld.com. It is as though the line:

```
        t.AddQueryOption("site", "computerworld.com");
```

is being ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I know I can do a site specific search by building the URI myself rather than using the library. What I want to know is how to use this library properly for site specific searches.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `site` property to `query` itself as follows:

```
var t = bingContainer.News("site:computerworld.com " + query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

This approach is outlined in a [related ASP.NET blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/07/04/integrate-bing-search-api-to-asp-net-application.aspx).

Comment: This does not work, it generates an incorrect RequestURI as follows: 
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/News()?Query='site%3Acomputerworld.comSQL%20Server'

Comment: @JonnyBoats This is the correct way to do it. The code originally shown was missing a space in the string concatenation, so it wasn't generating the query correctly.

Comment: @ScottDorman: Thanks for having my back on that while I ate dinner. :}

Comment: This is still not working, could I get you to try running your code? Thanks.

Comment: @JonnyBoats, Try changing it from a News search to a Web search, so `bingContainer.Web("site:www.Microsoft.com " + query, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: The `AddQueryOption` method effectively adds an additional query parameter to the URL. The "site" filter is actually part of the query syntax itself. You want to end up with a URL that looks something like https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27site%3Acomputerworld.com+sql+server%27 but I think you're ending up with a URL that looks something like https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27sql+server%27&site=computerworld.com. Try running Fiddler and look at the HTTP traffic. You should see the outgoing URL from your app and verify that it looks correct.

Comment: Bing should have a query parameter like Google's `as_searchsite` so that even a simple non-js form can be used without preloading the `q` field with the `site:searchdomain` text, which would only confuse a user.